# Python Popen() is blocking

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, jekyll, popen

I want to write a little python script to automate Jekyll blog creation, but `popen()` seems to block and not call asynchronously.

The expected behavior would be:

1. Start `jekyll serve --livereload` asynchronously
2. Start `firefox-esr http://127.0.0.1:4000` async and wait for it(, or synchronously, this is not relevant in my use case)
3. After termination of firefox, terminate Jekyll too.

```
jekyll = subprocess.Popen(['jekyll', 'serve', '--livereload'])
print('This never gets displayed')
time.sleep(3)
firefox = subprocess.Popen(['firefox-esr', 'http://127.0.0.1:4000'])
firefox.wait()
jekyll.terminate()
```

But this only starts Jekyll and outputs its stdout to the terminal.

This problem only appears with Jekyll. `ping` or any other command/program i tried work fine.

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: Does it show any errors in the terminal?

Comment: No. it shows the jekyll stdout. When killing the python script via ctrl+c the jekyll process is not terminated if that helps.

Im quite confused, as i did a completely similar thing with another piece of software, an it worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you try any other command instead of `Jekyll`  which doesn't constantly output something in the terminal, and check the terminal for output/error. And are you sure that you have `firefox-esr`.

Comment: when reversing the commands, firefox gets started, then jekyll starts blockingly.
With other commands like `ping` i have no issues.
Are you aware of an hotfix? Maybe writing a bash script that only calles jekyll that i could call asynchronously and then terminate.
It clearly seems to be a problem with Jekyll.

Comment: I am not aware of a hotfix, but bash script could help, or even threading could help but not sure though. I will try doing it on my local machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Linux, you can create a simple `bash` script for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

jekyll serve --livereload & 
sleep 5
firefox-esr http://127.0.0.1:4000 &>/dev/null


pid=$(pgrep firefox-esr)

while :
do
    sleep 5
    if [ -z  "$pid" ]
    then
        pkill ruby 2>/dev/null
        echo "Killed jekyll"
        break
    fi
done
```

Give this file execution permissions with

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

Then run this `bash` script with

```
./filename.sh &
```

This will make your script run in the background.

Comment: Thank you very much! But unfortunately, this does not work:

It starts Jekyll and firefox fine (but a little typo in the address) but it also fails to kill jekyll for some reason.

Comment: I took a look at htop and modified your answer.
htop says the command is ruby2.5 <path to jekyll>.

Killing ruby does the trick for me but is arguably brutal. I can live with the consequences as i use ruby only for Jekyll, but others may not.

Thank you very much, i am thinking of accepting this answer for me.